# range.copyTo not working as excpected Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

When i use the `range.copyTo(`) method to copy ranges from one spreadsheet to another, i usually will use `sheet.getLastRow()+1` when im specifing the destination range. Example:

```
 var oldRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());

 var newRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

If the destSheet does not have any additional or "blank" rows at the bottom, the `range.copyTo()` method does not copy the data and it does not throw an error message. If I use this same logic and use `.getValues()` and `.setValues()` , the new rows will automatically get added to my destSheet.

I was expecting `range.copyTo()` to create additional rows as well if needed. Is this acting as excepcted or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

If you add a .setValue('') to your newRange statement you'll see an error message **AND**  more rows will be automatically added to the destination sheet **AND** data will be copied.
Note that you shouldn't define the whole dest.range, only the top left cell is relevant as said in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range?hl=fr-FR#copyTo)

like this :

```
  var newRange = sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1).setValue('');
  oldRange.copyTo(newRange)
```

Anyway, this is not really the best workaround because of the error message (*We're sorry. The server encountered an error. Please press "OK" to refresh the sheet*.).  I guess one can reasonably consider this is a bug and you could raise an issue on this [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry)

EDIT : there is actually a nice workaround that I didn't think of immediately : you can use `insertRowAfter(ss.getLastRow())` before the copyTo() and everything works fine.
example :

```
  var oldRange = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn());
  var newRange = sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1);
  ss.insertRowAfter(ss.getLastRow())
  oldRange.copyTo(newRange)
```

Of course, if more than 1 row is needed repeat as necessary like in this example :

```
function copyToTest() {
  var oldRange = sh.getRange(1, 1, 5, ss.getLastColumn());// 5 rows in this example
  var newRange = sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1);
  for(n=0;n<oldRange.getLastRow();++n){ss.insertRowAfter(ss.getLastRow())}
  oldRange.copyTo(newRange)
}
```

Comment: I did file it as a bug using the link you suggested. Until they get back to that, i'll code around it with the insertRowAfter. Thanks for your help.